# Drawing surrounding rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I add a surrounding rectangle on top of the other nodes and edges in a tikz diagram? When I use the command `\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,40)` all the other components start below this point. What I would like is something in this diagram

[image]

My tikz code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{vertex} = [fill,shape=circle,node distance=80pt]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [fill,opacity=.2,fill opacity=.5,line cap=round, line join=round, line width=50pt]
\tikzstyle{elabel} =  [fill,shape=circle,node distance=30pt, opacity = .2]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}



\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}



\node[vertex,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{11}, \$30\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v1) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v1,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{21}\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v2) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v2,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{31}\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{6}\)}] (v3) {};



\node[vertex,below of=v1,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{12},\$40\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v4) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v4,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{22},\$20\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v5) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v5,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{32},\$20\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{6}\)}] (v6) {};



\node[vertex,below of=v4,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{31},\$45\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}\)}] (v7) {};

\node[vertex,below of=v5,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{32},\$50\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{4}, F_{5}\)}] (v8) {};

\node[vertex,below of=v6,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{33},\$40\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{4}, F_{5}\)}] (v9) {};



\node[vertex,below of=v7,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{41}, \$30\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}\)}] (v10) {};

\node[vertex,below of=v8,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{42}, \$70\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{4}, F_{5}\)}] (v11) {};



\draw[edge,color=yellow,line width=65pt] (v2) -- (v3);

\draw[edge,color=red,line width=65pt] (v1) -- (v5);


\draw[edge,color=blue,line width=65pt] (v10) -- (v8) -- (v6);


\draw[edge,color=green, line width=65pt] (v10) -- (v11) -- (v6);


\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[elabel,color=yellow,label=right:\(\$25\)]  (e1) at (7,0) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e1,color=red,label=right:\(\$30\)]  (e2) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e2,color=blue,label=right:\(\$70\)]  (e3) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e3,color=green,label=right:\(\$90\)]  (e4) {};

%Task nodes

\node[above of=v1,label={[font = \Large]above:\(Task \ T_1\)}] (t1) {};

\node[above of=v2,label={[font = \Large]above:\(Task \ T_2\)}] (t2) {};

\node[above of=v3,label={[font = \Large]above:\(Task \  T_3\)}] (t3) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't specify the coordinates, or relative position, of a node, it's placed at (0,0). That means the C_11-node is at (0,0). All the other nodes are to the right and/or below this, so naturally a `\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,40);` won't fit around the first column, as the positive direction of the y-axis is upward. Also, since the default unit vectors are 1cm long, you'd get a rectangle that is 10cm by 40cm, which is far too large.

Of course using some other coordinates for the `rectangle` path would work, e.g.

```
\draw (-1,1.2) rectangle (1,-9.8);
```

but you could also use the `fit` library. Add `\usetikzlibrary{fit}` to the preamble, and

```
\node [draw, fit=(v1)(v10), inner sep=30pt] {};
```

in the diagram. That will make a node that fits around the `v1` and `v10` node. The `inner sep` is a little more than half the `line width` used in the `edge` style.

Unrelated comments: `\tikzstyle{foo}=[..]` is generally considered deprecated in favour of `\tikzset{foo/.style={...}}`. And in the top labels, don't make `Task` a part of the mathematical expression. Write e.g. `Task \( T_1 \)` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
  vertex/.style={
     fill,
     shape=circle,
     node distance=80pt},
  edge/.style={
     fill,
     opacity=.2,
     fill opacity=.5,
     line cap=round,
     line join=round,
     line width=50pt},
  elabel/.style={
     fill,
     shape=circle,
     node distance=30pt,
     opacity = .2}
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[vertex,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{11}, \$30\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v1) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v1,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{21}\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v2) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v2,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{31}\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{6}\)}] (v3) {};


\node[vertex,below of=v1,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{12},\$40\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v4) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v4,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{22},\$20\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}, F_{2}\)}] (v5) {};

\node[vertex,right of=v5,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{32},\$20\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{6}\)}] (v6) {};


\node[vertex,below of=v4,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{31},\$45\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}\)}] (v7) {};

\node[vertex,below of=v5,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{32},\$50\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{4}, F_{5}\)}] (v8) {};

\node[vertex,below of=v6,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{33},\$40\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{4}, F_{5}\)}] (v9) {};



\node[vertex,below of=v7,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{41}, \$30\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{1}\)}] (v10) {};

\node[vertex,below of=v8,label={[font = \Large]above:\(C_{42}, \$70\)}, label={[font = \Large]below:\(F_{4}, F_{5}\)}] (v11) {};


\draw[edge,color=yellow,line width=65pt] (v2) -- (v3);

\draw[edge,color=red,line width=65pt] (v1) -- (v5);


\draw[edge,color=blue,line width=65pt] (v10) -- (v8) -- (v6);


\draw[edge,color=green, line width=65pt] (v10) -- (v11) -- (v6);


\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[elabel,color=yellow,label=right:\(\$25\)]  (e1) at (7,0) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e1,color=red,label=right:\(\$30\)]  (e2) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e2,color=blue,label=right:\(\$70\)]  (e3) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e3,color=green,label=right:\(\$90\)]  (e4) {};

%Task nodes

\node[above of=v1,label={[font = \Large]above:Task \( T_1\)}] (t1) {};

\node[above of=v2,label={[font = \Large]above:Task \(T_2\)}] (t2) {};

\node[above of=v3,label={[font = \Large]above:Task \(T_3\)}] (t3) {};


%\draw (-1,1.2) rectangle (1,-9.8);

\node [draw, fit=(v1)(v10), inner sep=30pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```